# "go get" ignores GOPROXY when using http_proxy

Tags: go, proxy

I'm trying to get Go to use an internal enterprise Go-Proxy for module download - which requires an http_proxy to be accessible (enterprise firewall). However `go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint` fails:

> package golang.org/x/lint/golint: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/lint/golint": https fetch: Get "https://golang.org/x/lint/golint?go-get=1": Forbidden

My setup:

- `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables are set
- `no_proxy` does not contain the IP or hostname of my Go-Proxy
- `GOPROXY` is set (`go env -w GOPROXY=https://artifactory.mycompany.com/api/go/myrepo-go-virtual`)

I checked:

- Using curl and directly querying the GOPROXY server works fine and I can download the file (so the https_proxy setting works)
- Counter-check with curl and explicitly unsetting http/https_proxy: No connection, as expected

Using tcpdump, I discovered that running `go get` seems to ignore my GOPROXY and ask my http_proxy to connect directly to the original url on golang.org (Options/sequence and ack numbers omitted for brevity), which the proxy/firewall blocks.

```
06:52:53.926397 IP <my_ip.port> > <proxy.port>: Flags [S], length 0
06:52:53.927206 IP <proxy.port> > <my_ip.port>: Flags [S.], length 0
06:52:53.927232 IP <my_ip.port> > <proxy.port>: Flags [.], length 0
06:52:53.932003 IP <my_ip.port> > <proxy.port>: Flags [P.], length 89: HTTP: CONNECT golang.org:443 HTTP/1.1
06:52:53.932638 IP <proxy.port> > <my_ip.port>: Flags [.], length 0
06:52:53.933100 IP <proxy.port> > <my_ip.port>: Flags [P.], length 3939: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

**Question:** Why does Go ignore the GOPROXY? Did I not set something up correctly?

I'm using Go 1.15.3 in the `golang:1.15.3` Docker container (with some added tools to check connectivity)

Comment: Does `go env` display the `GOPROXY` variable set to a value you expect it to be set to?

Comment: @kostix Yes, it does. Both when I use `go env -w GOPROXY=...` to set it, and when I just use `export GOPROXY=...`

Comment: Do you have `GONOPROXY` set by chance (see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39835#issuecomment-649827269))?

Comment: I don't think so: go env shows it to be empty (`GONOPROXY=""`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:  set `GO111MODULE=on` to use `GOPROXY`
Or run `go mod init` before you run `go get`

Comment: `GO111MODULE=on` did the trick. Thank you - this was driving me insane.

Comment: see this page if you want to go deeper :<https://dev.to/maelvls/why-is-go111module-everywhere-and-everything-about-go-modules-24k>

Comment: @ws_, why one would need to set this with Go 1.15.3? Do you mean the (weird) superposition of these two facts: 1) the OP has his project checked out under GOPATH and 2) when working under GOPATH the `GOPROXY` is not considered as `go` is working in non-module, legacy, mode?

Comment: @kostix  Your describtions are correct. In go proxy provider's site,usually they would provide this instruction like `goproxy.io`. The better way is to run `go mod init` before `go get` to use `GOPROXY` and forget about `GO111MODULE` .