# Defined GOPROXY not being used

Tags: docker, go, proxy, goproxy

I'm trying to download artifacts from github.com through my company proxy for go artifacts. Below is the command I've defined in the docker file for downloading buf

```
RUN GOPROXY=https://go.ci.artifacts.company.com/artifactory/golang-go-release-remote,direct go install \
    github.com/bufbuild/buf/cmd/buf@v1.19.0
```

But the build fails with the below error

```
13:28:10  ---> Running in 829d352a2aa5
13:28:15 go: github.com/klauspost/compress@v1.16.7: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/klauspost/compress/@v/v1.16.7.zip: 403 Forbidden
13:28:18 Could not build image: The command '/bin/sh -c go mod download' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can someone help me with the reason for why the defined proxy is not used & the downloaded is attempted using https://proxy.golang.org/github.com ?

Also I've tried adding below commands in the docker file before download but the defined proxy is not used

```
ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN go mod init
```

as per the comments in the question ["go get" ignores GOPROXY when using http_proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458372/go-get-ignores-goproxy-when-using-http-proxy?rq=2)

Comment: In docker try replacing `RUN go mod init` with `RUN go mod init main`

Comment: what is the need to do it ? can you pls explain ?

Comment: Does not work. Still the same error

Comment: `go mod init` requires a module name argument, so that should be failing. you don't need to set `GO111MODULE=on`.  The command that is failing is a different command from the one where you set `GOPROXY`.